# How to use Python and openCV to merge the contours of the same object?

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I have used the function named cv2.findContours() to draw the outline, however some places could not be identified which made the contours discontinuous. Here is my code and the result.
Thanks a lot if someone could teach me how to merge the contours of the same object?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("/home/rafael/Desktop/2.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([50, 10, 10])
upper = np.array([120, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
d_im = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 1)
e_im = cv2.erode(d_im, kernel, iterations = 1)
src, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(e_im, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
temp = []
tmp = []
num = 0
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if len(contours[i]) < 35:
        temp.append(i)
for i in temp:
    del contours[i - num]
    num = num + 1
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite('/home/rafael/Desktop/13.jpg', image)
```

Result

[image]

The full picture

[image]

[The original Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9POxU.jpg)

Comment: check before findcontour process, the image contains full object or not. With Morphological operations you may miss some part in the object.

Comment: Maybe you need to attach the actual input image, if you really want somebody to have a close look at your problem :)

Comment: @HowardGENG I have attached the full image, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Maybe if you increase the contrast beforehand? or apply thresholding?

Comment: @Gowthaman Yes, you are right, actually I have found that when I changed the original image to the binary image, some parts have been missed, but changing the threshold may not help solve the problem, so could you tell me how to check and solve it?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Actually some part had been missed when changed to the binary image, because the missing parts' RGB is very similar with the background(gray), methods could not identify then even I used HSV.

Comment: did you tried for converting gray scale image to binary using adaptivethreshold ?

Comment: @Gowthaman I have tried it but the result didn't look good.

Comment: Can you share the input image, that will give better idea                         
@RafaelHuang- If my comments are useful, give upvote.

Comment: @Gowthaman I attached the original picture, you can have a try.